# $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$, where $f(z)=\frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^3}+\frac{x^8}{y^2+1}i$.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, continuity

$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$, where $f(z)=\frac{xy^3}{x^3+y^3}+\frac{x^8}{y^2+1}i$.

I'm trying to find the limit of this function. I've tried several directions, $x=y, x=y^2, etc$ but they all ended up with the value $0$. However, I cannot prove that the limit is $0$ either. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

Comment: And what is $\;z\;$ , anyway??

Comment: @Timbuc $z=x+iy$

Answer (score 1):

You have trouble on the line $y=-x$.  The function isn't defined along that line, so the limit doesn't exist.
To check, try a curve that is tangent to $y=-x$, say $y=-x+x^2$.

Comment: Isn't it enough to consider only points that are in the intersection of a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ and the domain of the function. So we can ignore points in which the function is not defined. Also I tried $y=-x+x^2$ and still got $0$...Could you explain where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: $xy^3/(x^3+y^3)=(-x^4+3x^5-3x^6+x^7)/(3x^4-3x^5+x^6)\to-1/3$